# Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer Default Value overwriting actual property value

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have a bean which is populating properties using the @Value annotation like this

```
@Value("${propbean.value : 'None'}")
private String value;
```

In my application context I have the following configuration

```
<bean id="propbean"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
      p:location="file:${path}/values.properties"
      p:ignoreResourceNotFound="true"
      p:ignoreUnresolveablePlaceholders="true" />
```

When the values.properties file is not present, the defaults 'None' are being set as expected, however when the properties file *is* present, the default values are still being used, even though I receive a log message that the properties file was loaded from the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

```
190315 14.23.44,517 {} {} {} INFO  (PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172) Loading properties file from URL [file:/path/to/file/values.properties]
```

I need the default values to take effect *only* when the properties file is missing and/or the placeholders are not resolveable; not all the time. I have also tried using SPEL, but because this is a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer object as opposed to using the  directive the SPEL solution doesn't work for me. It's my understanding that when using the ${value : default} format for placeholders that the default is only substituted when the value is null, however if I remove the " : 'None'" from the value placeholder the property resolves correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps someone in the future - the problem was the  `p:ignoreUnresolveablePlaceholders="true"` property in the bean definition. Apparently that instructs Spring to ignore the properties being read into the bean altogether no matter what if there is a default value set.

Removing the property/setting to false resolves the problem completely.